# R read a corpus prepared for iramuteq

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I have a long text file prepared for iramuteq. It looks like this :

```
**** *au_coll *a_2007
L’assemblée plénière des évêques de France, après avoir décidé de la mise en place de trois groupes de travail, s’est terminée ce jour avec le discours de clôture de Mgr André Vingt-Trois, archevêque de Paris et nouveau président de la Conférence des évêques de France.
Sur proposition du Comité études et projets, présidé par Mgr Jacques Perrier, évêque de Tarbes et Lourdes, les évêques ont voté pour la mise en place de trois nouveaux groupes de travail sur les sujets suivants :
Bioéthique ; Indifférence religieuse et visibilité de l’Eglise catholique ; Usage et devenir des bâtiments d’églises.
L’assemblée plénière a élu présidents de ces groupes de travail : Mgr Pierre d’Ornellas, archevêque de Rennes, pour le groupe de travail « Bioéthique » ; Mgr Claude Dagens, évêque d’Angoulême, pour celui qui concerne « Indifférence religieuse et visibilité de l’Eglise catholique » ; Mgr Roland Minnerath, archevêque de Dijon, pour le travail sur « Usage et devenir des bâtiments d’églises ».

**** *au_mgrrault *a_2007
L’itinéraire qui vous a conduit à devenir évêque de Laghouat mérite attention. Pourquoi êtes-vous devenu prêtre et qu’est-ce qui vous a amené à vivre en Algérie?
Mon itinéraire a été celui d’un jeune séminariste au départ. Pendant mes études de philosophie au séminaire de Coutances, je pensais déjà à devenir missionnaire. J’ai rêvé un moment de partir en Amérique latine. Un Père Blanc du Burkina Faso est venu nous parler au séminaire de Coutances du choc de la culture Mossi et de l’Evangile. J’ai été séduit par son témoignage et j’ai «basculé» après mon service militaire chez les Pères blancs : noviciat à Gap, puis, première expérience de « déculturation » au Canada anglophone (Ottawa) pour mes études de théologie. Pendant ces études, un confrère, venant d’Afrique du Nord, m’a communiqué sa passion pour la relation avec l’islam et les Musulmans. J’ai été nommé en Algérie en 1970 comme directeur adjoint d’ un centre professionnel regroupant 70 jeunes Algériens. Je suis ensuite parti à Rome où j’ai appris l’arabe classique, puis je suis revenu comme moniteur de jeunes en échec scolaire à Ghardaïa. Le centre où je travaillais a été fermé au moment de la nationalisation en 1976 . J’ai alors fait ma valise pour Touggourt (Est saharien) pour enseigner l’anglais dans un collège de l’Enseignement public algérien. Plus tard, j’ai pris une année sabbatique à Sainte Anne de Jérusalem. J’ai découvert la vie des communautés chrétiennes palestiniennes puis celles du Liban lors d’un séjour dans la Bekaa. Revenu en Algérie en 1980, j’ai retrouvé un poste de professeur vacataire d’anglais à Ouargla, puis, revenu à Ghardaia en 1983, je me suis engagé comme apprenti dans atelier de fabrication de plateaux en cuivre chez un artisan où je suis resté trois ans. Ce fut une belle expérience d’humanité. En 1987, Mgr Jean-Marie Raimbaud (diocèse de Laghouat) m’a nommé vicaire général, chargé de la formation permanente. Son successeur, Mgr Michel Gagnon m’a reconduit dans cette charge en 1991. Nous étions entrés dans « les années noires » (celles du terrorisme) et en 1994, J’ai été appelé en Suisse pour devenir responsable du noviciat des pères Blancs à Fribourg, qui a été transféré à Bobo-Dioulasso (Burkina Faso) en 97. J’ai dû quitter le Burkina en 99, ayant été nommé Provincial des Pères Blancs pour l’Algérie et la Tunisie. C’est au cours de ce mandat que j’ai été appelé comme évêque de Laghouat-Ghardaia (Sahara Algérien) et ordonné par Mgr Michael Fitzgerald le 16 décembre 2004. Je suis évêque d’un diocèse dont la superficie couvre quatre fois la France. Nous avons onze points de présence sur cette immense étendue. Le diocèse compte entre 20 et 25 prêtres et religieux, 40 religieuses. Les Religieuses sont surtout engagées dans la promotion féminine, la petite enfance et les personnes handicapées, souvent avec l’aide de partenaires algériens. Nous tenons à soutenir et à favoriser ce partenariat, notamment dans le cadre d’associations. Dans le domaine parascolaire, nous sommes sollicités pour les cours de soutien scolaire, l’animation de bibliothèques, et un Centre culturel de documentation saharienne. Nous faisons aussi de notre mieux pour venir au secours des personnes migrantes en détresse venant du Sub-Sahara, avec une aide à leur retour au pays, en lien très étroit avec l’ Association, « Rencontre et Développement », fondée par la CIMADE.
Qu’aimeriez-vous partager d’important sur la vie en Algérie aujourd’hui?
Mon attachement au peuple algérien. Les algériens m’ont apporté leurs qualités d’accueil, les richesses de leur différence et de leur diversité. Je leur apporte aussi les miennes. Il est possible de s’accueillir et de vivre ensemble différents grâce à l’ouverture de son cœur et de sa maison : la convivialité renforce les liens de la fraternité, et prépare un dialogue plus profond. Les Algériens aujourd’hui veulent tourner la page sur les difficultés du passé et vivre une nouvelle page avec les Français. Le peuple algérien nous fait découvrir ce qu’est la grandeur de la Transcendance. Le fait que des assassinats aient été faits au nom de Dieu a interrogé profondément l’Islam ambiant et la conscience de nos amis musulmans. Il y a aujourd’hui un grand désir de rencontre, et nos échanges portent davantage sur des questions existentielles que sur des problèmes théologiques : le sens de la vie, de la mort, de la naissance, de la souffrance. Malgré la fragilité de notre présence et de nos petits moyens, nous collaborons à l’avènement d’une société plus humaine, plus à l’image de celle du désir de Dieu. Je retrouve là des aspects de la religion populaire de nos familles chrétiennes. Des gestes simples traduisent la grandeur de Dieu. Le réveil de l’Islam en France est une saine provocation pour notre Eglise et pour la société occidentale en quête de sens. Nous sommes tous en quête de sens. L’autre est important, que cet autre soit Dieu ou mon prochain. L’Autre est Dieu. Bien recevoir de l’Autre, l’accueillir, est un acte religieux. Ce que m’apprennent aussi les Algériens , c’est la patience, savoir attendre ! J’admire la patience de mes amis musulmans, une patience élevée à la dimension d’une vertu religieuse. Notre manière d’être chrétien c’est de comprendre l’Autre différent dans la gratuité, au nom de l’Amour de Dieu, sans que cet Amour aboutisse à une tentative de récupération. C’est l’attitude de Jésus dans l’Evangile. Jésus a rencontré sans récupérer. Il a parlé en laissant les gens repartir. Etre présent en ayant les mains nues. Nous vivons avec tous au nom de la gratuité de l’Amour de Jésus. Notre vocation est de vivre cette fraternité. Beaucoup de Musulmans manifestent un grand Amour pour nous. Si pendant les années difficiles les chrétiens ont pu rester en Algérie, c’est grâce à ces Musulmans qui eux ont subi beaucoup de violence, et ont beaucoup souffert. Malheureusement, aujourd’hui l’Algérie, tout en étant riche de ressources n’a peut-être jamais eu autant de pauvres. La presse algérienne en parle abondamment. C’est pourquoi il y a toujours ce rêve de jeunes Algériens de vouloir partir en France. Comment peut-on aider à créer des emplois en Algérie ? Un état peut être riche et pauvre. Le pétrole n’est pas actuellement assez créateur d’emplois. Il est certain que les Responsables politiques sont alertés sur ce point. Espérons toujours des temps meilleurs !
Qu’avez-vous découvert lors de cette Assemblée plénière ?
C’est la troisième Assemblée plénière à laquelle je participe.. C’est plus passionnant pour moi que la première, où j’avais tout à découvrir. Je m’exprime librement soit dans l’hémicycle soit plus largement avec les autres évêques et je peux ainsi partager leurs soucis de pasteurs et leurs questions. C’est un lieu de communion et de vraie fraternité épiscopale. J’ai l’impression que l’ensemble de l’épiscopat s’ouvre aux problèmes de société et de relations interreligieuses que pose l’Islam. C’est un regard serein, une bonne vision réaliste pour aller de l’avant. Il y a encore beaucoup de chemin à faire, mais cette attitude positive a une répercussion sur l’Eglise Universelle, et aussi sur notre Eglise du Maghreb. Nous sommes voisins : beaucoup de Maghrébins ont franchi la Méditerranée et sont maintenant citoyens français, et cela nous engage à un plus grand souci de dialogue et entre Eglises et entre partenaires chrétiens et musulmans.
En savoir plus sur le diocèse de Laghouat
 »Créé en 1868, d’abord comme « Vicariat Apostolique du Sahara et du Soudan » par le Cardinal Lavigerie, le diocèse de Laghouat-Ghardaia s’étend sur une superficie de plus de deux millions de Km². Il recouvre la partie Sud de l’Algérie (le Sahara). La population est surtout présente dans les oasis, devenues maintenant de véritables villes (Djelfa, Laghouat, Ghardaïa, Ouargla, Bechar, Tamanrasset …) Elle s’élève à un peu plus de 3.000.000 d’habitants, soit 10% de la population algérienne pour 90 % du territoire national. Au cœur de ce monde musulman, les services et les membres du Diocèse sont animés par l’évêque, Mgr Claude Rault. La communauté diocésaine est essentiellement formée de prêtres, religieux et religieuses et de quelques laïcs, tous engagés dans la pastorale de la rencontre avec nos frères et sœurs musulmans. La communauté chrétienne totale peut être évaluée à environ 1000 personnes, prenant en compte les chrétiens engagés dans les différentes sociétés pétrolières présentes dans la région. C’est dans ce diocèse qu’a vécu Charles de Foucauld, il a résidé successivement à Beni Abbès et à Tamanrasset où il est mort dans les conditions tragiques que l’on sait. Son tombeau se trouve à El Goléa depuis 1929. Mgr Hippolyte Simon (nouveau vice-président de la Conférence épiscopale de France), Mgr Michel Santier, ancien évêque de Luçon et nouvellement nommé à Créteil, deux de ses anciens compagnons de collège, sont allés lui rendre visite au cours de l’année passée. Mgr Stanislas Lalanne, nouvel évêque de Coutances et Mgr Michel Dubost, sont allés aussi le visiter cet été en Algérie »
```

And I would like to read it directly in R and consider the segmentation by `****`

The `corpus` function from the `tm` package doesn't work well...

any ideas ?

Comment: What about sth in the veins of `Corpus(VectorSource(strsplit(txt, "****", TRUE)[[1]]))`?

Comment: `txt` is my variable ? How can I read the `file.txt` ?

Comment: E.g. `txt <- paste(readLines("file.txt"), collapse="\n")`, if it's a text file (and not a binary one).